# Html Form submit EventListener doesn't work, not sure why?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, addeventlistener

As shown below I have html document with a div containing only the following form.

```
<div class="search-section">
    <form id="formid" class ="search-bar">
        <label for="input" >Search City</label>
        <input type="text" id="input" value="" class="search input">
        <button type="submit" class="search btn"> SUBMIT </button>
    </form>
 </div>
```

In my Js file I have tried to add a on submit Event listener, however the submit event doesn't even seem to fire. if I try different events like on click or on change it seems to work but submit for some reason doesn't and I don't know why. I am a beginner so any help or explanation would be grateful. below is the js code.

```
    const inputField= document.querySelector('#input'); 
    const form= document.querySelector('#formid'); 
    
    form.addEventListener('submit', () => {
        const cityName = inputField.value;
        const api = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=${apiKey}&units=metric`;
        inputField.value = '';

        fetch(api)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                }
            })
            .then(data => {
               renderResponse(data)
            })
            .catch( networkError => {
                locationTimeZone.textContent = networkError.message;
            });
    });
```

I know the form is the correct one because I have console logged it, and I can't see any problem with my button or form.

Comment: Add `event.preventDefault();` to your event (and add `event` as an attribute to the function)

Answer (score 2):

Your event is firing and it is reloading the page. At least this is what I expect as you are not preventing the default action.

```
const inputField= document.querySelector('#input'); 
const form= document.querySelector('#formid'); 

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const cityName = inputField.value;
    const api = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=${apiKey}&units=metric`;
    inputField.value = '';

    fetch(api)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
           renderResponse(data)
        })
        .catch( networkError => {
            locationTimeZone.textContent = networkError.message;
        });
});
```

This will stop the form from continuing the HTTP request to your current page. Check out this link for more information.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event

Answer (score 0):

try this one. I hope this could help you

```
 const inputField = document.querySelector('#input');
 const form = document.querySelector('#formid');
 
 //@TODO API KEY
 const apiKey = '<API_KEY>';

 form.addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {
   evt.preventDefault();
   //@TODO remove this alert
   alert('form is submitted!');
   
   const cityName = inputField.value;
   const api = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=${apiKey}&units=metric`;
   inputField.value = '';

   fetch(api)
     .then(response => {
       if (response.ok) {
         return response.json();
       }
     })
     .then(data => {
       renderResponse(data)
     })
     .catch(networkError => {
       locationTimeZone.textContent = networkError.message;
     });
 });
```